# what is the principle of low latency in trading application?

Tags: c, trading, low-latency

It seems that all the major investment banks use C++ in Unix (Linux, Solaris) for their low latency/high frequency server applications. How do people achieve low latency in trading high frequency equity? Any book teach how to achieve this?

Comment: Simple: write fast code; run it close to the exchange.

Comment: ... where "close to the exchange" generally means "in the same server room".

Comment: @Jan: or so I've heard, sometimes "equidistant between the two exchanges across which you are attempting to perform arbitrage".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://g-wan.com/

http://www.zeromq.org
http://www.quantnet.com/forum/threads/low-latency-trading-system.3163/
check these websites you may get some idea about low latency programming.
but be aware that some codes may not be standardized. Which means it will not for longer time
it may creates some bugs in it.